# Can't update to 1903 Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I'm currently using Windows 10 1809 and I can't update to 1903 version. When I open Windows Update, it always shows this:
[Windows Update screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4Qja.png)

And when I use Update Assistant to update my laptop, it always shows an error. My laptop ASUS F560U, which was released in Q3/2018, so the laptop isn't that old or anything.

Comment: What error does it show?

Answer (score 0):

Its better that you wait...you will get the update after a few weeks but if you don't want to wait, then head to this link: 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Click "Update Now" and proceed with the on-screen instructions.

If this doesn't work, then download the windows 10 iso from the same page using the media creation tool and then manually update it.